# How to join more than 5 tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to join multiple tables with SQL.
Here is my table structure:

```
table 1: akdhis_mahasiswamagister (ID, MahasiswaID, NIM, MayorID, TahunMasuk)
table 2: akdmst_mayor(ID, DepartemenID)
table 3: ipbmst_departemen(ID, FakultasID, DepartmenName)
table 4: ipbmst_fakultas(ID, FacultyName)
table 5: ipbmst_orang(ID, Name, NIMS2Key)
table 6: akdhis_kelanjutanstudi(ID, NIM, IPK)
```

I want to create "a view table" by joining with this query:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `aIPK` AS select 
`ipbmst_fakultas`.`Kode` AS `Fakultas`,
`ipbmst_departemen`.`Kode` AS `Departemen`,
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` AS `NIM`,
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`TahunMasuk` AS `TahunMasuk`,
 `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`IPK` AS `IPK`
from (((((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister` left join `akdmst_mayor` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`MayorID` = `akdmst_mayor`.`ID`))) 
left join `ipbmst_departemen` on((`akdmst_mayor`.`DepartemenID` = `ipbmst_departemen`.`ID`))) 
left join `ipbmst_fakultas` on((`ipbmst_departemen`.`FakultasID` = `ipbmst_fakultas`.`ID`))) 
left join `ipbmst_orang` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` = `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key`))) 
left join `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi` on((`akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`NIM` = `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key`)))
WHERE IPK IS NOT NULL

order by NIM
LIMIT 100;
```

but, when I tried to run it, the result is empty result. What should I do to solve that problem? Thankyou

Comment: Do you get results when you remove you `WHERE` statement? Also, this has nothing to do with the number of tables being joined, but rather how you are joining and filtering. I suspect that IPK is null for every returned record. Your LEFT OUTER JOIN's suggest that the field `IPK` is in one of those LEFT JOIN'd tables. The fact that it's null suggests that your `ON` clause for that join is either bad, or you've made a bad assumption about the relationship between the two tables being joined.

Comment: when I remove WHERE statement, the result of IPK is NULL. So, what should I do to solve that problem? @JNevill

Comment: maybe a union is what you need? if there are no rows in the mahasiswa table, the result will always be empty even when there is data in the others.

Comment: I shouldn't make a difference, but try removing every bracket - none of them are needed.